# Facebook CheckIn integration to ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins

Is it possible to use the Facebook Checkin API on our ASP.NET MVC website?

I am using Javascript SDK for Facebook login in my website. 
I have to integrate Facebook CheckIn in my website.

Comment: The Facebook checkin API was removed with version 1.0 of the Graph API. What exactly are you looking to do?

Comment: Yes, Facebook checkin API is removed. Is It possible to post a message with location using Javascript

Comment: Yep you should be able to do that! Check out the Post documentation for the Fields that can be used for creating a Post. I believe you will want to use the 'place' field. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post

Comment: How can I get the post id?

Comment: It is all documented in the link I placed above, if you have a logged in user you can get their posts by making a request on the Graph API to the /<USER_ID>/posts endpoint.

Comment: Is it necessary to submit the app for review to get the permission of publish_actions?Can I check it with any test app?

Comment: You will need to submit for review BEFORE you launch the app to the public. If you are an Admin or Developer of the app you do NOT need to submit for review before using the permission.